# Captivate 7 - passing a completion after opening a "Open URL or file command" in a Multi SCO Course

Tags: javascript, adobe, training-data, adobe-captivate, scorm1.2

```
Background:
Courseware Development Platform: Captivate 7
Backend - Meridian 
Using - SCORM 1.2
SCORM Packager: Adobe Multi SCO Packager 7
```

We have been developing some of our courses in Captivate 7 and I have been seeing a constant degradation in the ability for Captivate 7 to handle certain commands or end a course with the integrated course credit command.

My first issue was identified and fixed by creating/updating the utility.js file and changing the  doCPExit to just:

```
Finish();
LMSFinish();
```

This worked great for a few months but as of this month I cannot get this fix to allow us exit the course with credit specifically in multiple SCO courses packaged developed in Captivate 7 and using SCORM 1.2 standard.

We have a robust IT Team here but I need to be able point to the issue with some sort of confidence and my hope is someone else is having the same issue and might have some insight on how they were able to troubleshoot this.

My second question is about SetValue and passing a completion directly to our LMS using the JavaScript button...what is the best way to accomplish this? My JavaScript skill are limited and my fear is I may be missing "fixes" to this problem with bad JavaScript writing.

My third and final question is in regards to the open a URL/file button we use for a survey within Captivate it ends the communication session and refuses to give completion after we open this in a new window (using it inside Captivate crashes it), my initial thought is completion never gets written to the LMS and im looking for good ways to send it before we open the window to ensure a completion for the user... these are not tests just courses we need credit given on.

Thanks to all who look this over and take the time to help me navigate these issues.

-Stephen T.
Instructional Designer for CSX

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at it here... sounds like Captivate uses Rustici's SCORM Driver.

You could try to call CommitData(); before Finish(); to essentially force the saving of the student attempt.

Its supposed to try and Commit in Finish but without seeing the version and implementation thats a best guess.  I don't know what LMSFinish() is doing, as thats not present in the SCORM Driver.

Only other guess is I'm not sure what triggers doCPExit().  I've seen some cases where body events like onload and on on unload don't work reliably.

Bookmarklet may assist seeing whats going on up until you exit i.e. is their even a score before you exit?  http://cybercussion.com/bookmarklets/SCORM/

Thanks,
Mark